# Java: Get Value of an object and parse it as a long

Tags: java, object, long-integer

I have an object which its first field is a number (BigDecimal, int...). I want to parse it to a long but when parsing it it says that the method "ValueOf" is not applicable for Object.

I have tried this.

```
if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {

        for (Object[] obj : list) {
            Object obj1 = obj[0];

            Dto dto= new Dto();

            dto.setId(Long.valueOf((obj[0])));
```

But there is an error

Comment: Try to use obj[0].toString() before call value of

Comment: You got to parse the object before calling valueOf. Btw: Use `StringUtils.isEmpty()` for your condition instead of your AND-concat.

Comment: Why do you want to convert a `BigDecimal` to a `Long`? You're potentially chopping off numbers if you do.

Answer (score 1):

Call toString and parse it to a Long value:

```
 dto.setId(Long.parseLong(obj[0].toString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Long.parseLong(obj[0].toString());
```

`Long.parseLong()` expects String without any formatting symbols inside.

If you don't care about the format, consider using `Long.toString()` to convert a long value into string and `Long.parseLong()` to convert it back.

There is also this method: `Long.valueOf(str)`; Difference is that `parseLong` returns a `primitive long` while `valueOf` returns a `new Long() object`.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient approach is to cast it to a Number.

```
public static long asLong(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Number 
           ? ((Number) o).longValue() 
           : Long.parseLong(o.toString());
}
```

Note: this handles error cases differently.  For example if you have `new BigDecimal("2.5")` using longValue() will return `2` but Long.parseLong("2.5") will throw an exception.  It depends on what behaviour you prefer.